# How to install specific version of ffmpeg (4.2) in colab?

Tags: ffmpeg, google-colaboratory, torchvision

I need a specific version of ffmpeg to be able to read video with torchvision (0.12.0+cu113), which currently supports ffmpeg 4.2. I have already tried to upgrade ffmpeg with the next command:

```
add-apt-repository -y ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4
```

But it gives me a version 4.3.2. How to install exactly 4.2?